# Unique constraints on members of embedded member in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to define unique constraints on members of an embedded class in Hibernate?

I need to be sure that Nested::i1 and Nested::i2 are unique as a pair (the combination)

```
@Entity
@Table( uniqueConstrains = ???)
public class Widget {
   @Id
   private int id;

   @Embedded
   Nested nested;
}

@Embeddable
public class Nested {
    private int i1;
    private int i2;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible by using:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"i1", "i2"})})
public class Widget {
```

It would result in `CREATE` SQL (postgresql example)

```
create table Widget 
(  id int8 not null,
   i1 int8, 
   i2 int8 ,
   primary key (id),
   unique (i1, i2)
)
```

Optionally - it would be probably more consise and readable when you add `@AttributeOverride` annotation specyfying in one file - column names for both attributes

```
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "i1", column = @Column(name = "i1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "i2", column = @Column(name = "i2"))
})
@Embedded
Nested nested;
```

Comment: Thnaks, this is great. One thing worries me a lot, is that if the field names of `Nested` change, any class using it as embedded will have problems ... any patterns to solve that problem?

Comment: @JoshuaMN unfortunately there's no pattern for that, but the chances that `Nested` class's fields will change their names are rather small assuming purpose of embedded classes usage. You can also abandon the idea of `@AttributeOverride` as in this case it does mean nothing (I just think the code is more consise when using it).